# read textoutput and skip current loop

Tags: bash, process

I have a script with a loop over some directories and in each of them it executes a program.

```
folders=( "1" "2" )
for i in "${folders[@]}" 
do 
cd $i 
output=$(program)
while read -r line; do
match "$line"
done <<< "$output"

some code here

cd ..
done
```

Now i want the script to stop the running `program` if `$line` matches with a given string and then start working on the next element of `${folders[@]}`. Basically Strg+c from inside the script.

Edit: I cannot access the program and make it stop itself should the string appear.

Thanks

Comment: That's a convoluted idea. Fix the `program` to exit when it generated the given string.

Comment: i cannot access the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i want the script to stop the running program if $line matches
>   with a given string

```
if [ "$line" = "Put some similar text in here" ]
then 
exit 0
fi
```

This will stop the programm, like you wanted.

> then start working on the next element of ${folders[@]}

This is something different.

You can try to switch the code like this ...

```
folders=( "1" "2" )
for i in "${folders[@]}" 
do 
 cd $i 
 output=$(program)
 while read -r line; do
  if [ "$line" = "Put some similar text in here" ]
  then 
   break
  fi
 done <<< "$output"
# some commands ...
done
```

The `if` condition checks for similar text in a string and the `break` command will close the `while loop`.

---

**Addition**

The same code without using `$output` as temporary storage...

```
folders=( "1" "2" )
for i in "${folders[@]}" 
do 
 cd $i 
 while read -r line; do
  if [ "$line" = "Put some similar text in here" ]
  then 
   break
  fi
 done <<< "$(program)"
# some commands ...
done
```

This way you will `exit` the extern programm in the loop.

Comment: if the while loop is closed, does that mean the program gets stopped too?

Comment: Nope, `break` will close the loop only. You need to use `exit 0` instead to close the programm.

Comment: To be clear: with programm I mean this script! You put all output from your extern programm into `$output` after the extern programm is done it will start the loop. There is no need to kill the extern programm in your case.